# How to remove duplicates and keep most recent entries in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to sort through data within Excel. How do I remove duplicates within Column A but keep the most recent year entry in Column B and most recent month date in Column C?

Comment: Have verified that the "remove duplicate" Excel feature does not do what you want?

Comment: When I 'Remove duplicates', it does not keep the most recent in the other columns.

Comment: Do a better job of explaining your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has the ability to remove duplicates from a select dataset.

> In Excel, you have several ways to filter for unique values or remove
>   duplicate values:
>
> - To filter for unique values, use the Advanced command in the Sort & Filter group on the Data tab.
> - To remove duplicate values, use the Remove Duplicates command in the Data Tools group on the Data tab.
> - To highlight unique or duplicate values, use the Conditional Formatting command in the Style group on the Home tab.

Source: [Filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Instructions:

1. Switch to the **Data** tab:

[image]

2. Highlight the range of data you want to remove duplicates from
3. Hit **Remove Duplicate**

[image]

4. Select the columns you want to remove duplicate data from

[image]

5. Click **OK**

[image]

6. Done

[image]

> When you remove duplicate values, only the values in the range of
>   cells or table are affected. Any other values outside the range of
>   cells or table are not altered or moved.
>
> Because you are permanently deleting data, it's a good idea to copy
>   the original range of cells or table to another worksheet or workbook
>   before removing duplicate values.

Source: [Filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Nice tutorial answer!